# Access overridden global variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, overriding

I want to access global variable 'x' when it is over-ridden by same named variable inside a function.

```
function outer() {
   var x = 10;
   function overRideX() {
      var x = "Updated";
      console.log(x);
   };

  overRideX();
}

outer();
```

Jsbin : [Fiddle to Test](http://jsbin.com/oxalux/3/edit)

I don't want to rename the inner 'x' variable to something else.
Is this possible ?

Edit: Edited question after abeisgreat answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window.x to reference the globally scoped variable.

```
var x = 10;
function overRideX() {
  var x = "Updated";
  console.log(x);
  console.log(window.x);
};

overRideX();
```

This code logs "Updated" then 10.

Comment: Yeah..But that won't work everytime. Imagine a case when the whole above code is inside another function. Then window.x won't work. And I will face the same issue.

Comment: Then it will depend on the specific case, however, I would suggest getting in the habit of naming your variables more clearly. Having several variables named the same thing (especially single characters) gets very confusing.

Comment: Thanks abeisgreat. But this question is just out of curiousity.

Answer (score 1):

The global scope of your web page is `window`. Every variable defined in the global scope can thus be accessed through the `window` object.

```
var x = 10;
function overRideX() {
    var x = "Updated";
    console.log(x + ' ' + window.x);
}();
```