# JavaScript local and global variable confusion

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I was doing some practices on local and global variable scopes. Following is my code([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjmBf/1/)):

```js
var myname = "initial"
function c(){
    alert(myname);
    var myname = "changed";
    alert(myname);
}
c();
```

When the first alert is called, it is showing `myname` as undefined. So my confusion is why I am not able to access a global instance of `myname` and if I don't define `myname` within the function then it will work fine.

Comment: if you do   **alert(window.myname);** then you will get values

Comment: @dholakiyaankit I've tried using window.myname still it is saying undefined...

Comment: @BharatSoni window.myname works in my browser.

Comment: It should work bharat

Comment: @dholakiyaankit I've tried in fiddle.. didn't work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xjmBf/6/ in my browser this is also working

Comment: It may not be working in the fiddle because the jsfiddle might have it's own scope, though I don't know enough about jsfiddle to say for certain.

Comment: var myname = "initial" isn't a global variable. It can be accessed only from that current scope that javascript is. If you want to declare a global variable do it without the "var" keyword, and thar variable should be a property in the window object.

Comment: Every function gets its `this`, unlike fat arrow they dont have own `this`,but they can related reuse to closest context `this`, now, js look for variable from current context if not found go a step upward look in closest parent context if present in it or so on

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In JavaScript, the variable declarations are automatically moved to the top of the function. So, the interpreter would make it look more like this:

```js
var myname = "initial"
function c(){
    var myname;
    // Alerts undefined
    alert(myname);
    myname = "changed";
    // Alerts changed
    alert(myname);
}
c();
```

This is called [hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Scoping_and_hoisting).

Due to hoisting and the fact that the scope for any variable is the function it's declared in, it's standard practice to list all variables at the top of a function to avoid this confusion.

Comment: that I've understood, so there is now way to access a global variable with same name as local variable.. ??

Comment: You should be able to access it by doing `window.myname`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826751/access-overridden-global-variable-inside-a-function But global variables are not usually considered a good practice, and in most cases it'd be better to define a global object and access it through that. i.e. `var me = { myname: "initial" }` then call `me.myname` in the function.

Comment: It is not correct to say that variables declaration are moved on top. For example if on line 10 it is written var myname = "initial", the result we see is not like var myname = "initial" on line 1, but actually we see the behavior as if var myname is on line 1 and on line 10 it is assigned value i.e. myname = "initial"

Comment: Also, note that using `var myVariable` outside a function does not automatically make it a global. Often declaring `myVariable` with nothing in front makes it a global (unless its already scoped/set earlier in the function), but its always better do use `window.` when doing so. Then again, just avoid globals in general where possible :P

Answer (score 9):

It is not replacing the global variable. What is happening is called "variable hoisting". That is, `var myname;` gets inserted at the top of the function. Always initialize your variables before you use them.

Try this:

```js
var myname = "initial";

function c() {
    alert(myname);
    myname = "changed";
    alert(myname);
}

c();
```

Comment: sir, I am not just trying to change the value.. what you are doing is changing the value of global variable itself.. I want to understand the concept "WHY" it is happening...

Comment: This fixes the problem of alerting undefined, but it eliminates any local variables as it's only using the global variable `myname`.

Comment: It is not replace the global variable. What is happening is called "variable hoisting". That is, myname var myname; gets inserted at the top of the function. Always initialize your variables before you use them you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938961/understanding-global-local-scope-in-javascript?rq=1