# Variables defined in addEventListener JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, addeventlistener

I have the code below in the beggining of my JS scirpt. When I try to print any of defined variables below that code, the console says that variables are not defined. Can you tell me why? Maybe I should call the funtion first?
When I define variable below and then print it to the console, it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     var homeElement = document.getElementById("home");
     var childElements = document.querySelector(".oferts").children;
     var banner = document.querySelector(".ban");
     var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
     var links = document.querySelector(".links").children;

 });

 console.log(homeElement); //Here I got info that this variable is not defined
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: because console.log line is executed before the DOM is ready and your listener is called. Also, your variables seem to be locally scoped for that handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables were defined locally and cannot be accessed outside the function.

You can remove the `var` keyword to make the variables global and you will be able to call the variable anywhere in the script.

Read about JavaScript scope

[Javascript local and global variable confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721313/javascript-local-and-global-variable-confusion)

[Demystifying JavaScript Variable Scope and Hoisting](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

[JavaScript Scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try to log your variable inside of function

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
     var homeElement = document.getElementById("home");
     var childElements = document.querySelector(".oferts").children;
     var banner = document.querySelector(".ban");
     var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
     var links = document.querySelector(".links").children;

     console.log(homeElement);// <--
 });
```

Your issue occures beacuse `homeElement` doesn't defined in outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems here:

1. The `var X` inside the scope set that variable as local variable (and not global) so you can't use it outside the scope.
   You can set the variable to global if you use `var X` in the global and only `X = ...` inside the scope.
2. Based on your code - the `console.log` function runs before the function in the callback of `addEventListener`, so at the time of running - the variable was not set, yet.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the variables are being created in the scope of the event listener's function, while console.log is executed in the global scope. The global scope does not have access to the variable scope.

You can either move the console.log into the function, or declare the variables outside the function.

Answer (score -1):

You create your variables inside your function so they are only accessable inside of it.

To make global accessable variables you can simply change it to the following:

```
 var homeElement;
 var childElements;
 var banner;
 var blocks;
 var links;

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   homeElement = document.getElementById("home");
   childElements = document.querySelector(".oferts").children;
   banner = document.querySelector(".ban");
   blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
   links = document.querySelector(".links").children;
 });

 console.log(homeElement);
```

Comment: Actually I wrote this answere while other ones were written. I read other answeres after I posted mine. What's wrong with my answere?

Comment: Didn't say it was wrong, only that when you posted it there were already 3 answers saying that (and at least one of them saying that).